# Get online users from big record table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a big data record from onlines table. (more than 40 Million record)

now i want to show online user in any time from the table but this execute from server has been failed ...

for example when i send request get online in last week , it's dose not work (because the table have very large record).

this is my example php code:

```
$d = $_GET['date'];
$time   = time() - 60*60 * 24 * $d;
$phql   = "SELECT DISTINCT aid FROM onlines WHERE time > '$time'";
```

so, do you have any better tips ?

Tnx.

Comment: ___Its does not work___ In what way does it not work. Do you get an error message, if you do would you like to share it with us, **just for fun**

Comment: Try replacing '$time' with ' ".$time." ' and also bind your parameter to prevent sql injection.

Comment: also share example of column `time` values ?

Comment: @Bonzo There is nothing wrong with the query as it stands.

Comment: everything is work fine. But when too much record, the server can not respond.

Comment: So **what error do you get** Have you looked at the php error log and/or the mysql error log

Comment: no any error, when i run the sql query and after one  minute or mor , the  web browser show "This site can’t be reached"... I think i have to change config php.ini :-/

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see which indices are defined on your table. Ensure that particularly for big tables, that your columns that you query are indexed. In this case `time`.

You can create an index by:

```
CREATE INDEX time_index ON onlines (time);
```

This should speed up the query. If you do not care about potential data loss or persistance you might look into using an in-memory table to avoid IO. That speed up queries significantly but will empty the table if the server restarts or MySQL is shut down.